# NotSupportedException with Value Generation and CastingConverter in EF Core 2.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Since upgrading an application to EF Core 2.1, I have started getting the exception below. I suspect that it has something to do with the new [Value Conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions) (though I haven't manually implemented a `ValueConverter`). Any ideas how to resolve? I want to maintain database-driven auto increment values for the `Snapshot.Id` column mentioned. The same code-base works fine on EF Core 2.0. The database schema was all built via EF Core code-first.

If there is any other code I could provide that would be helpful, let me know. This could be a bug in EF or even my EF provider, but I can't find any related issues.

Exception:

> NotSupportedException: Value generation is not supported for property
>   'Snapshot.Id' because it has a 'CastingConverter' converter
>   configured. Configure the property to not use value generation using
>   'ValueGenerated.Never' or 'DatabaseGeneratedOption.None' and specify
>   explict values instead.

EF Model Builder Snapshot:

```
modelBuilder.Entity("Data.Entities.Snapshot", b =>
{
    b.Property<int>("Id")
     .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
     .HasColumnType("MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED");

    ...

    b.HasKey("Id");

    b.ToTable("snapshots");
});
```

Property Configuration:

```
public virtual void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> entityTypeBuilder)
{
    entityTypeBuilder.Property(x => x.Id)
                     .HasColumnType("MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED");
    ...
}
```

Other Info:

- Database: MariaDB
- EF Provider: Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 2.1.0-rc1-final

Opened GitHub Issue:

- https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/601

Comment: It sounds like the type doesn't match and EF auto-generated a type converter.  Are you sure that your database's Id column is an int?

Comment: @DavidL Thanks, I just added more info to the question. In the db, the property is actually an unsigned smallint.

Comment: What happens if you change the initial HasColumnType to SMALLINT?

Comment: Typo in my initial question, it's actually MEDIUMINT. But, tried dropping "UNSIGNED" from HasColumnType and now that error doesn't occur. I get the same exception now on another Id column of another table. Going to continue working through removing UNSIGNED... I want to preserve UNSIGNED in the db, though, since negatives don't make sense for an auto-incrementing id column.

Comment: Yep, the issue is with UNSIGNED. That should be supported, I would think, though. Maybe a bug? Ideas if this would be a bug with EF or the EF Provider?

Comment: To be honest I don't know the EF Core library as well as EF 6, but to me that seems like a bug.  I'd recommend you open an issue on the GitHub repo.  Glad you figured out a workaround however.